# appengine memcache setting different expiration for different object

Tags: google-app-engine

Can I set different expiration time for different object in appengien memcache? Or the expiration time I provide is global for all the objects in memcache. I think that expiration time is for all memcache values, from [the appengine doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/usingjcache#Configuring_Expiration) : `The app can specify a expiration time for valueS, a maximum amount of time the value will be available.` Can someone confirm me please?

Comment: It would be (more than) a bit weird if the timeout argument to put changed the expiry time on every object in the cache.

Comment: yeh, I guess but I have some problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057803/appengine-memcache-using-jcache-not-expiring and reading the doc stating "time for Value`S`" and thought that maybe, that's how it should be. a newb mistake ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have different expiration times for different objects in memcache
Get the cache instance via `MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService()`
Then use void `put(java.lang.Object key, java.lang.Object value, Expiration expires)`
Source: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService#put%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20com.google.appengine.api.memcache.Expiration%29

Comment: yeh, but can I set different expiration time for different object?

Comment: Yes you can,  
Eg:  
memcache.set("foo", "bar", time=32)  
memcache.set("ham", "eggs", time=64)  
now "foo" has 32 secs of expiry while "ham" has 64 secs of expiry

Comment: hmm... I  tried https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/usingjcache#Configuring_Expiration for individual java object but I still see the object after the expiration time. Am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: ok, Once you Get cache instance via `MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService()`
Use [put](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService#put%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20com.google.appengine.api.memcache.Expiration%29)

Comment: I see. I have to use the low level API instead of JCache. Thanks!